# Создание заказа через woocommerce rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Работаю через WooCommerce REST API PHP Client Library – https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library.
Пытаюсь создать order, библиотека дает такой метод:

```
$client->orders->crate($data);
```

Вот вся фунцкия целиком:

```
public function create( $data ) {
    $this->set_request_args( array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body'   => $data,
    ) );
    return $this->do_request();
}
```

Вопрос – что именно и в каком виде нужно передавать в $data, что бы order создался?

Answer (score 1):

Уверен что в документации есть все параметры.
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order

```
$data = [
'payment_method' => 'bacs',
'payment_method_title' => 'Direct Bank Transfer',
'set_paid' => true,
'billing' => [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'address_1' => '969 Market',
    'address_2' => '',
    'city' => 'San Francisco',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'postcode' => '94103',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'phone' => '(555) 555-5555'
],
'shipping' => [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'address_1' => '969 Market',
    'address_2' => '',
    'city' => 'San Francisco',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'postcode' => '94103',
    'country' => 'US'
],
'line_items' => [
    [
        'product_id' => 93,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 22,
        'variation_id' => 23,
        'quantity' => 1
    ]
],
'shipping_lines' => [
    [
        'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
        'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
        'total' => 10
    ]
]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('orders', $data));
```